# Coldfusion continuous high CPU usage

Tags: coldfusion

At our office, we have a development server : Win 2k8 server R2 - Coldfusion 9(.0.0) - MySQL 5 ...

Almost every morning when I arrive at work, I find the server with the CPU at 50%. But... What does he do ?
See the screenshots : 
[image]
[image]

You can see that the CPU is +- 50% of use and it's well jrun.exe who does that!
To trying to understand what's happened, I go to the Server monitor and, no active thread or request! The monitors are declaring that nothing is happened...

There is no scheduled task programmed.

Do you have an advice for me? Somewhere where I can get more information?

Thank you.

---

Update 20 June:
A new week begin and my server still works for nothing :)
Now I can monitoring him with VisualVM but I don't know where I had to look.

Monitor:
[image: visualVM Graph's]

Threads:
[image: visualVM Threads]

CFStat :
[image]

I don't know which running process is driven to consume CPU...

Comment: @orangepips Can it slow down a server when monitoring with visualVM ? I mean, is it cost a lot of ressource ?

Comment: there's a small amount of overhead. I've run load tests where the difference is 10-20ms per request. That noted, both cfstat and the server monitor can crash you server with OOM exceptions if turned on for long periods of time.

Comment: @orangepips ok thx. And, if no visualVM is listening the server, it still consume ressource ? I mean, does the JVM parameters (`-com.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8701 ...`) can remain on a production server?

Comment: yes, you can leave it in the JVM's configuration. Be aware if don't password protect it, anyone can connect.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried running `cfstat`?

```
C:\ColdFusion9\bin>cfstat 1 -x
```

Please change the directory above to your CF install directory.

The `-x` flag will show Flash remoting and web service requests too.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! I've never heard of `cfstat` !
[http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf3638e6-7fe0.html](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf3638e6-7fe0.html)

I'll take a look.